# Spring Bean declaration error

Tags: spring

**applicationContext.xml code like above：**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><beans  
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" >
```

**the error message like above：**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

so,what's the kind of the question and how to fix the error? thanks advanced!!

Comment: Is this a full content of applicationContext.xml?

Answer (score 0):

## EDIT

There should be a new line after schema/beans something like this:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" >
```

Comment: what's the reason why? just the different between location

Comment: anubhava,thank you for you helping,but i don't understand what the different between you answer and my applicationContext.xml.

Comment: @Jameswq: You need to ENTER a new line in you applicationContext.xml after `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` to avoid that error. So above text should be in 2 lines not in the same line.

Comment: thank you very very much , i will try it later and tell you the result.

Comment: morning! i tryed it later yesterday.the error point is at the end of 'xsi:schemaLocation','spring-beans-2.5.xsd' should be 'spring-beans-2.0.xsd'.of course.the jar package's version is spring 2.0.so the web app running.whatever,thank you so much.